# Laravel 8 Bootstrap Doesn't Read bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I installed bootstrap in Laravel 8 using the ff commands:

`npm install --save bootstrap jquery @popperjs/core cross-env`

Inside `app/resources/js/bootstrap.js` included the ff stabs:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Then inside `app/resources/scss/app.scss` I included bootstrap:

```
// bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Finally, on my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").sass(
    "resources/scss/app.scss",
    "public/css"
);
```

Upon using a view to test if bootstrap is working, I included it like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

This however did not work and bootstrap did not load. Any idea how to properly load bootstrap so I can use each codes?

Comment: Did you run `npm run production`? That will run the laravel-mix scripts and generate the .js and .css files in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and check update files in public/js and public/css:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```